# Combination of values in object attributes typescript

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if there is a construct in typescript that I can use in order to restrict possible values of an object depending on the values. I can describe it something like that:

```
interface IObject = {
key1:string;
key2:string;
key3:"A" | null;
key4: (if key3 is 'A' then allow 'value1' |'value2' else if it is null then allow "value3" | "value4" 
}
```

Does typescript support that?

Comment: Yes it almost does. The questions are almost similar, but the exact match is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the type like this:

```
type IObject = {
  key1:string;
  key2:string;
} & ({
  key3:"A",
  key4: 'value1' |'value2'
} | {
  key3: null,
  key4: "value3" | "value4" 
})
```

We basically create a union of all valid `key3` and `key4` combinations and intersect them with the rest of the properties.